# Find the range of lines that an identifier was being used with awk

Tags: linux, awk

I am having a file as :

**file1.txt**

```
1  10  ABC KK-LK
1  33  23  KK-LK
2  34  32  CK-LK,LK
11 332 2   JK@
21 525 1   JK@
31 902 9   JK@
11 23  2   JK2
```

I am trying to see the number of lines being used by identifiers in 4th column:

```
KK-LK 1-2
CK-LK 3-3
JK@   4-6
JK2   7-7
```

If I apply the code below, I can have the `number of lines`, but it prints it in a new line rather than a `range`, which would be a problem since each `identifier` has at least `1 million lines`:

```
grep -n "KK-LK" file1.txt | awk -F  ":" '{print $1}'
1
2
```

How can I convert this to a range?

Comment: what if lines with same identifier are in different positions, what should be the range in that case?

Comment: Well, I have sorted it, so in case that they are not consecutive, it would sort first and then do the range?

Comment: for line 3 `CK-LK,LK`, why the `LK` is dropped in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ if ($4 in a) sub(/-[0-9]+/, "-"NR, a[$4]); else a[$4] = NR"-"NR }
     END{ for (i in a) print i, a[i] }' file
```

The output:

```
JK2 7-7
CK-LK,LK 3-3
JK@ 4-6
KK-LK 1-2
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{a[$NF]=a[$NF]?a[$NF] OFS FNR:FNR} END{for(i in a){num=split(a[i],array," ");if(num>1){print i,array[1] "-" array[num]} else {print i,a[i]"-"a[i]}}}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
{
  a[$NF]=a[$NF]?a[$NF] OFS FNR:FNR}
END{
  for(i in a){
    num=split(a[i],array," ");
    if(num>1){
      print i,array[1] "-" array[num]}
    else{
      print i,a[i]"-"a[i]}
}}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '{if($NF in a) b[$NF]=NR; 
        else a[$NF]=b[$NF]=NR} 
    END{for(k in a) print k,a[k]"-"b[k]}' file | sort -k2 | column -t

KK-LK     1-2
CK-LK,LK  3-3
JK@       4-6
JK2       7-7
```

or, since `NR>0`

```
$ awk '!a[$NF]{a[$NF]=NR} {b[$NF]=NR} END{for(k in a) print k,a[k]"-"b[k]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a one-pass fashion like this:

*parse.awk*

```awk
# Initialize start-line and id variables
NR == 1  { s=1; id = $4 }      

# When the id no longer matches print the range
$4 != id { 
  print id ": " s "-" NR-1

  # Reset variables for the next id
  s=NR; id=$4
}

# Print the last range when EOF occurs
END { 
  print id ": " s "-" NR
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk infile.txt
```

Output:

```
KK-LK: 1-2
CK-LK,LK: 3-3
JK@: 4-6
JK2: 7-7
```